# spring-ws bean-validation of unmarshalled @RequestPayload

Tags: jaxb, bean-validation, spring-ws

Is it possible in spring-ws 2, to get unmarshalled payload for validation with jsr303.
The idea is to have this done for every endpoint that I create without explicitly creating validation code in every endpoint. (for example with an interceptor or some kind of listener)

I tried extending the EndpointInterceptor but, there is no unmarshalled object here.
I also tried implementing Unmarshaller.Listener for the jaxb unmarshaller. Registered this through spring context but there are 2 issues here:
1. It only sets unmarshaller listener while initializing jaxb-marshaller bean.
2. Jaxb Unmarshaller is created on every request and listener is not set during the creation of unmarshaller for that specific request. I dont see a way to inject this on every request.

So is there any other way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to use AOP this is the way to go:

1. You will need to extend the DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter and implment Ordered in an subclass (for example:

   DefaultMethodEndpointAdapterWithJSRValidation extends   DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter implements Ordered {...)

**Make sure that you override following in your subclass:**

1.1 In this method you will add your jsr validation stuff:

```
@Override
public Object[] getMethodArguments ...
```

1.2 This method makes sure that your bean is used in stead of the default bean.

```
@Override
public int getOrder() {
  return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

1. You can than register you bean in the spring context like this:

`<bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter" class="your.package.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapterWithJSRValidation" primary="true"/>"`

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

As Spring WS endpoints are normal Spring Beans, you can just make use of Spring's AOP functionality and create an aspect for validating the passed objects.

If you're using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate Validator 4.2 as Bean Validation provider you can make also use of Hibernate Validator's [method validation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customoptions-methodvalidation) feature. Spring provides an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.html) which performs method validation for all beans annotated with [@Validated](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html).